# Correct usage of comma vs addition sign in node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm following a tutorial on setting up an Application with Node.js and noticed they use `,` instead of `+` when console  logging certain variables.

I realise that `,` returns the righthand value, but when is the correct time to use `,` instead of `+`?

When I `console.log` using `+` I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
```

When I use `,` it returns as expected.

Comment: The console.log function accepts variadic arguments. You can pass it as many "things" as you want not just one. This has nothing to do with the comma operator per se

Answer (score 0, accepted):

those are just two similar ways of logging something out. Syntax:

```
console.log("This is the logged variable: "+ variableName)
console.log("This is the logged variable: ", variableName)
```

I think your problem is that instead of logging out some existing variable, you may be trying to mutate the variable type, like converting the object to a string.

FYI, if you are using EcmaScript 6 (ES6) version of Javascript, there's a much neater way of doing the same thing using backticks, like so:

```
console.log(`This is the logged variable: ${variableName}`)
```

Comment: This makes sense and +1 for the extra ES6 info!